# Capybara: Check children of a div having class

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, capybara

I am trying to check if a `div` has a child with particular class in Capybara, using the following piece of code:
`expect(find("#admin-row-1 .glyphicon-ban-circle")).to_not be_empty`

Upon debug, I get the following output

```
(byebug) find("#admin-row-1 .glyphicon-ban-circle")
#<Capybara::Node::Element tag="a" path="/html/body/main/div[2]/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[3]/a[2]">
```

But still, getting the following expectation error

```
Failure/Error: expect(find("#admin-row-1 .glyphicon-ban-circle")).to_not be_empty
       expected #<Capybara::Node::Element tag="a" path="/html/body/main/div[2]/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[3]/a[2]"> to respond to `empty?`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`find` returns an element or raises an exception, it doesn't return anything tha responds to `empty?`,  You could use `all` instead which returns an array like object but a better solution is to use the have_css matcher provided by Capybara

```
expect(page).to have_css('#admin-row-1 .glyphicon-ban-circle')
```

Comment: It works the same way as `expect(page).to have_selector('#admin-row-1 .glyphicon-ban-circle')` ? What is difference between `have_css` and `have_selector` ?

Comment: Have_selectors first parameter is the type of capybara selector (the selector in have_selector is referring to capybara selector, not necessarily CSS) and if not specified defaults to Capybara.default_selector which defaults to :css. have_css(...) calls have_selector(:css, ...), so it's the same thing but makes it clear you're using css as opposed to :xpath, :field, :select, etc.